# Get moving hover effect on different div with "content" property

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is when you hover mouse over div1 it will effect links div

When hovering div1:

```
div .div1:hover ~ linksdiv:after    {
display:inline-block;
transition-duration: all 1s;
color:#FFF;
padding-left:50px;
content:"index";
```

linksdiv without hover:

```
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
transition-duration:1s;
transition-property:margin;
transition-delay:2s;
float:left;
margin-left:100px;
width:500px;
height:100px;
font-size:100px;
font-weight:900;
top:-230px;
content: string;
```

The purpose of this code is to have the text go white on a red background while giving a moving effect.
But all it does is display a white text.

This worked when I did not use "content" but instead had a finished written text in the div. :(

edit:
html

```
        <div id="surrounding">
        <div id="left">
            <div class="div1">
                <a href="index.html">index</a>
            </div>
            <div class="div2">
                <a href="media.html">media</a>
            </div>
            <div class="linksdiv">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <iframe id="content" src="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should really show your html.

Comment: @AlphaKitten Do you want to style the content of your `iframe`?

Comment: @ROX No I want to style .linksdiv with a moving effect.
.linksdiv has a content property that makes text appear when I hover one of the other divs

Comment: Please show the css class names for "**linksdiv without hover:**" like ???{.....} and try this - http://jsfiddle.net/ju23n0ob/